# Secure .Net API Calls via IP

Tags: asp.net-web-api

So pretty new to the API world.

**Scenario:**

Server 1 Runs a Web app that displays a web page with info called from Server 2.

Server 2 Runs a api service that **should only answer to Server 1**.

**ISSUE:**

User visits Server 1, and in the controller it calls server 2.

//Server 1

```
 public class IndexController : Controller
    {
     private WebProfile GetProfile(string id)
            {
      var client = new HttpClient();

                var builder = new UriBuilder(string.Format("{0}{1}", baseMapUrl, "/Profile"));
    builder.Port = 17608;
                var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);
                query["pId"] = id;
                builder.Query = query.ToString();
                string url = builder.ToString();

                client.BaseAddress = builder.Uri;
                //client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                var response = client.GetAsync("?pId=" + id);

                while (response.Status==TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation)
                {
                    //wait until my status changes
                    var a = response.Status;
                }
    var result = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    //do more stuff...
    }
}
```

//Server 2

```
[HttpGet]
 public class ProfileController : ApiController
    {
public Profile Get(string id)
        {
 var profile = new WebProfile();
//Go and do stuff, get data and return 
return profile;
}
```

So I created a firewall policy on Server 2 to only accept connections form Server 1 (IP) on port 17608.
But when tested, no traffic comes through to Server 2 as the call (IP) is not the IP address of Server 1, its the IP of the User visiting Server 1....

**What am I doing wrong?
How do I resolve this as Server 2 should only accept calls from the IP of Server 1?**

Comment: You could throw some encrypted value as a Cookie or Header on the request when it comes from Server 1 (that only server 1 would know) and then create your own Authorization Attribute that will validate the request(s).

Comment: By virtue Cross-Origin calls will fail and you will have to Enable CORS support on the WebAPI server where you're expecting to get calls from Server 1.

Follow [Enable CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) and see if resolves your problem